# some mod rewrited images are not loading. why?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

> example.com/thumb/AWg7X9Ko5hA_default.png

for example it is working....

but

> example.com/thumb/m0bt_9Qiznc_default.png

is not.. why not?

when i access

> example.com/thumb/media.php?id=m0bt_9Qiznc&type=default

it works.

this is the htaccess code that i use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^thumb/([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.png$ /thumb/script.php?id=$1&type=$2 [L]
```

and script.php:

```
$media_type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$the_id=$_REQUEST['id'];
if ($media_type=="big") 
{
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile("http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/$the_id/0.jpg");
}
elseif ($media_type=="default") {
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile("http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/$the_id/default.jpg"); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RewriteRule only allows for **two** parts separated by an underscore:

```
 RewriteRule ^thumb/([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.png$
```

But your URL has **three**:

```
 example.com/thumb/m0bt_9Qiznc_default.png
                     ^     ^      ^
                     1 _   2  _   3
```

So you probably want to change your first `[^_]*` into just `.*` for broader matches. Or use:

```
 RewriteRule ^thumb/([^/]+)_([^_]*)\.png$
```

Comment: thank you.                                                      i've used  `RewriteRule ^thumb/([^/]+)_([^_]*)\.png$` and now the images are loading just fine.  I could have any more problems using this code?

Comment: Cool. Instead of `([^/]+)` it would also work with just `(\w+)` as that matches letters, numbers and the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

It's the underscores.

The regex only allows for ONE underscore, but the second file name has two underscores in it.